# ubuntu installation failure

Tags: installation, virtualbox

I am trying to install **ubuntu 12.04** version using VM virtual box. I have windows 7 home premium machine. The things i did:

1. installed oracle's VM virtual box
2. downloaded desktop version of ubuntu's 32 bit 12.04 version ISO file
3. created a new session in VM virtual box by opting ubuntu. For this i choose, dynamic allocation, 2048 MB RAM, 60 GB, provided the path of ISO file i downloaded
4. After clicking start, it shows me screen to install. I selected the appropriate options. Everything goes well. After sometime it says installation is complete and asks to restart. if i click restart, my machine freezes and a window pop up comes saying things got corrupted and windows will look for best option for solution.
   After clicking that, it goes back to start i.e., in VM box, i see the machine as aborted status, so if i click that, it starts again from start, i.e., it ask me to install ubuntu again.

i tried even the latest version of ubuntu and the same issue happens.

Comment: here is the exct error i get  ------------- oracle VM virtualbox manager has stopped working
a problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available. ---------------

Comment: How much RAM does your system have?  what version VB have you installed?

Answer (score 0):

once you installed Ubuntu successfully you should remove the ISO file from the virtual box drives then it will not ask to install again..Give at least 2GB of ram space and enable/disable 3d acceleration based on your system configuration..